# How we can select single column from database in entity framework in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
student1Entities se = new student1Entities();
var ss = from l in se.accounts where (l.uname == txtuname.Text && l.password == txtpass.Text);
```

I want to login but can't get user name and password from database. If you know that please help me?

Comment: Before the semicolon, `select l.uname` (or whatever column you want)...

Comment: Do note that you have a huge security problem if you're storing passwords in plain text in your database...